# HIbernate load a relationship with depth 2

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, mapping

I have 3 classes
Class1 has a List with elements of class2.
This is mapped via  a jointable (can not be mapped with foreign key because key would not be unique)!

Class2 has an foreign key of class3.
Class3 doesnt save anything from this relationship.

The whole thing looks like this:

```
  Class1             Class1-2 jointable          Class2
+-----------+   +-----------+-----------+   +-----------+-----------+
| Class1_ID |   | Class1_ID | Class2_ID |   | Class2_ID | Class3_ID |
+-----------+   +-----------+-----------+   +-----------+-----------+
| 1         |   | 1         | 3         |   | 3         | 10        |
| 2         |   | 2         | 7         |   | 7         | 3         |
| ...       |   | ...       | ...       |   | ...       | ...       |
+-----------+   +-----------+-----------+   +-----------+-----------+

 Class3
+-----------+
| Class3_ID |
+-----------+
| 10        |
| 3         |
| ...       |
+-----------+
```

mapping looks like this:

```
Class1: 
List<Class2> class2;

<bag name="class2" cascade="all" table="Class1_Class2" lazy="false" access="field">
     <key column="Class1_ID" />
        <many-to-many class="Class2" column="Class2_ID"/>
```

```
Class2: 
Class3 class3

<many-to-one name="class3" class="Class3" column="Class3_ID" fetch="join" unique="false"/>
```

So when I load an element of class1 with session.load(Class1.class, id) I get the object.  BUT!
I can access class1.class2 (The list of elements) but when I try to access class1.class2.class3 it gives me an exception that lazy loading cannot be performed because there is no session.
Because of my data structure I cant have a session open at this point.
I need to load all with one DB access.

So now my question: Can I change the mapping that everything will be loaded at once? And if I cant how do I load everything in 1 session and return an Object of type class1 where i can access class1.class2.class3?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the XML configuration (syntax) but can't you use define the relation between `Class2` und `Class3` as eager like you did with the relation between `Class1` and `Class2` (`lazy=false`)? `fetch="join"` *should* set this value automatically but obviously it is not executed that way.

(I will not tell you the hack that just touching the objects while still within the session will load it (like `class1.getClass2().getClass3() // Slightly different in your case because of many-to-many`) because that would be a hack.)

> This is mapped via a jointable (can not be mapped with foreign key because key would not be unique)!

You can set a `unique` constraint on the key column via Hibernate. Then it may be even possible to select everything with one statement and joins (which automatically should be eager).